# MONYY7. and DATE9. operations

Tags: date, sas

I'm working on a very big data set, (more than 100 variables and 11 millions observations). In this data set, i have a variable named DTDSI (simulation date) in DATE9. format. (For example: 01APR2015 , 02MAR2015...). I have a macro-program to analyse this data set by comparing the observations in 2 different months:

```
 %macro analysis (data_input , m , m_1);
 .....
 %mend;
```

The 2 macro-variables m and m_1 are months that i want to compare. Their format is MONYY7.(APR2015 , MAR2015...). Keep in mind that i cannot modify my data_input (its the data of my company). In the beginning of my macro program, i want to create a new data set with only the observations of the &m and &m_1 month. I can easily do that by creating a new date variable from DTDSI (real_month for ex) but in the format MONYY7. Then i just select the observations where real_month equal &m or real_month equal &m:

```
Data new;
Set &data_input;
mois_real = input(DTDSI,MONYY7);
RUN;

PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE NEW AS;
SELECT *
WHERE mois_real in ("&m" , "&m_1")
FROM NEW;
....
```

The problem is that in my first Data Statement, i duplicated my data_input; which is bad because it took 30 minutes. So can you tell me how can i make my selection (DTDSI = m and DTDSI=m_1) right in my first Statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula's in your where/if condition, so apply your formula from step 1 into step 2 or vice versa.

```
Data new;
set &data_input;
WHERE put(DTDSI,MONYY7) in ("&m" , "&m_1");
run;
```

Comment: That won't quite work.  If I read things right, `dtdsi` is a date variable and `&m` is text structured like `MONYY7.` .  So, `where put(dtdsi,monyy7.) in ("&m", "&m_1");` seems right.

Comment: @Joe, uiquanghai Is dtdsi a text string or a numerical?

Comment: My assumption is that it's a numeric (from the question), but it's certainly not 100% clear.